# Demoting unnumbered section using newenvironment not working for subfile

Tags: table-of-contents, environments, subfiles

I am trying to export a *tex* using *subfile* into a main *tex* file. The file structure is the same for both the main file and *subfile*. The importing of the *subfile* is an addendum.
The *leveldown* of the section works file however it does not for the unnumbered section.
How can I also demote the un-numbered section so that it gets reflected in the TOC as a subsection?
The constraint being that I can influence the *subfile* structure before being imported in the *main.tex* file; just like I have done with the *leveldown* environment.
Any ideas/solutions/thoughts etc.
Thank you for your attention.
See my code below:
main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\title{Doc1}
\author{Author1}

\maketitle

\section*{Summary Doc}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary Doc}
\section{Doc 1 section}
Text
\subsection{Doc 1 subsection}
Text
\subsubsection{Doc 1 subsubsection}
Text
\paragraph{Doc 1 paragraph}
Text
\subparagraph{Doc 1 subparagraph}
Text
\section{Appendix}

\newenvironment{leveldown}% Demote sectional commands
  {\let\section\subsection%
   \let\subsection\subsubsection%
   \let\subsubsection\paragraph%
   \let\paragraph\subparagraph%
   %\let\subparagraph\relax%
  }{}
\begin{leveldown}
    subfile{doc2}
\end{leveldown}


\end{document}
```

the doc2.tex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\title{Doc1}
\author{Author1}

\maketitle

\section*{Summary Doc}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary Doc}
\section{Doc 2 section}
Text
\subsection{Doc 2 subsection}
Text
\subsubsection{Doc 2 subsubsection}
Text
\paragraph{Doc 2 paragraph}
Text
\subparagraph{Doc 2 subparagraph}
Text
\section{Appendix}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is not really about the `subfiles` package, but rather about the `\addcontentsline` command. Your leveling-down works fine also for the unnumbered sections. The problem is that you manually tell LaTeX to add a line to the ToC at `section` level, in the subfile, and this is what LaTeX does. Adjusting `\addcontentsline` in your `leveldown` environment is not really an option, as it is also used in the sectioning commands, including the leveled-down versions, so you would doubly level down the ToC entries.

Comment: Would it be an option to replace `\addcontentsline` (at least in the subfile) by `\myaddcontentsline`, such that we can level down the ToC entries by `\myaddcontentsline` without touching `\addcontentsline` used internally? If yes, I would `\let\myaddcontentsline\addcontentsline` such that it behaves like the normal command, but do something like `\renewcommand\myaddcontentsline[3]{\addcontentsline{##1}{sub##2}{##3}}` in your leveldown environment. Note the hack of adding `sub` to the second parameter.

Comment: Probably you should also add `\let\tableofcontents\relax` to your `leveldown` environment to suppress the ToC in the included file.

Comment: I see what you mean. It worked when I changed it in the subfile (*Doc2.text*) to ```\myaddcontentsline```, however that change should also be in the *main.tex* as well since they are replicas - kind of a nested loop. So when I use that ```\myaddcontentsline```in the *main.tex*, needless to add, it fails. The 2nd file is an addendum where  changes in the *main.tex* are reflected. The only leeway I have is making that new environment to influence changes to the addendum file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the constraints yet, but here is a first try, as a basis for discussion

- Put the definitions into the preamble of the mainfile, to make them accessible to the subfiles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\let\myaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newenvironment{leveldown}% Demote sectional commands
  {\let\section\subsection
   \let\subsection\subsubsection
   \let\subsubsection\paragraph
   \let\paragraph\subparagraph
   % \let\subparagraph\relax%
   \let\tableofcontents\relax
   \let\origaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
   \renewcommand\myaddcontentsline[3]{\addcontentsline{##1}{sub##2}{##3}}%
  }{}
\title{Doc1}
\author{Author1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\maketitle
```

- Start the subfile just with

```
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\title{Doc2}
\author{Author2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\maketitle
```

---

The sample code below generates the following documents.

[image]

[image]

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\let\myaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newenvironment{leveldown}% Demote sectional commands
  {\let\section\subsection
   \let\subsection\subsubsection
   \let\subsubsection\paragraph
   \let\paragraph\subparagraph
   % \let\subparagraph\relax%
   \let\tableofcontents\relax
   \let\maketitle\relax
   \let\origaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
   \renewcommand\myaddcontentsline[3]{\addcontentsline{##1}{sub##2}{##3}}%
  }{}
\title{Doc1}
\author{Author1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\maketitle

\section*{Summary Doc}
\myaddcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary Doc}
\section{Doc 1 section}
Text
\subsection{Doc 1 subsection}
Text
\subsubsection{Doc 1 subsubsection}
Text
\paragraph{Doc 1 paragraph}
Text
\subparagraph{Doc 1 subparagraph}
Text
\section{Appendix}

\begin{leveldown}
    \subfile{doc2}
\end{leveldown}
\end{document}

% doc2.tex
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\title{Doc2}
\author{Author2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\maketitle

\section*{Summary Doc2}
\myaddcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary Doc}
\section{Doc 2 section}
Text
\subsection{Doc 2 subsection}
Text
\subsubsection{Doc 2 subsubsection}
Text
\paragraph{Doc 2 paragraph}
Text
\subparagraph{Doc 2 subparagraph}
Text
\section{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Never mind, this worked when i added that block in the *main.tex* preamble to the *doc2.tex*.   Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Gernot - much appreciated.
The constraint being that whatever is incorporated in *main.tex* should also be in *doc2.tex* because they have the same format (i.e. Latex embeddings) but differ in writing content. So the block in the preamble (see code block below) of the *main.tex* should also be in *doc2.tex* i.e.

```
\let\myaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newenvironment{leveldown}% Demote sectional commands
  {\let\section\subsection
   \let\subsection\subsubsection
   \let\subsubsection\paragraph
   \let\paragraph\subparagraph
   % \let\subparagraph\relax%
   \let\tableofcontents\relax
   \let\origaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
   \renewcommand\myaddcontentsline[3]{\addcontentsline{##1}{sub##2}{##3}}%
  }{}
```

However, is there a way to send a flag to the documents that if this is an addendum then deactivate that block in the preamble but keep it on when its the *main.tex*.
Sending a flag is an example but there might be other means as my latex programming skills are plain shoddy.
I hope you get my drift.

Comment: Disregard this comment of mine. See my comments above to your 2nd response.